# Selecting an alias with a condition to factor into percentage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working query but I need to change one line of my select to a different calculation and I'm not sure exactly how I should do it

The current line is `Round((sum(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ))  / al.Number_of_dealers) * 100 ,2)  as Percentage_up_to_date`

This is currently taking the value for Days_within_window and dividing it by total number of dealers. However, I need it to check the `next_call_date` field in the dealers table and if `curdate() < next_call_date + interval 7 day` then count it. At this point, all dates are in that window so it should be 100% but it's showing lower percentages becuase of the prior calculation.

It should be saying: *Count number of dealers for this CSR where curdate < next_call_date + 7 days, and divide that by total dealers for this CSR.*

I tried

```
 Round((sum(al.Number_of_dealers where curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ))  / al.Number_of_dealers) * 100 ,2)  as Percentage_up_to_date
```

but the syntax is wrong so i'm getting an error, but that's kind of the logic I'm going for.

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be141/1
(Again, target output is 100% at percentage_up_to_date for all records in the fiddle )

Full Query:

```
    select 
      c.user as UserID,
      concat(u.firstn,' ', u.lastn) as name,
      count(*) as Number_of_recorded_events,
      sum(curdate() < d.next_call_date + interval 7 day) as Days_within_window,
      al.Number_of_dealers,
      Round((sum(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ))  / al.Number_of_dealers) * 100 ,2)  as Percentage_up_to_date
    From contact_events c
    join users u
    on c.user = u.id
    join dealers d
    on c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
    left join (
      SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_dealers
      FROM attr_list AS al
      JOIN dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
      where al.attr_id = 14
      GROUP BY user_id) AS al
    ON al.user_id = c.user
    GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: I think your query is correct. Should the number of contacts between a dealer and a user be the same as the number of dealers for a CSR?

Comment: Well the user and CSR are the same technically, our company just has some bad and redundant table structures. Basically, it's pulling the correct number of dealers associated with the CSR. But I want to get the number of those dealers where ```curdate() < next_call_date + 7 days```

Comment: You can fix the syntax error if you change `al.Number_of_dealers where curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day)` to `al.Number_of_dealers * (curdate() < d.next_call_date + interval 7 day)`. But that will not fix the logical error.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be141/38) is what you want, but I don't understand the logic. And expecting 100% in every row is a bad test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood what you were trying to do:

```
select 
    c.user as UserID,
    count(*) as NumberOfDailyContacts,
    al.NumberOfDealerContacts,
    Round((al.NumberOfDealers  / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  as Percentage_up_to_date
From contact_events c
join users u
on c.user = u.id
join dealers d
on c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
left join (
  SELECT al.user_id, 
  count(user_id) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + interval 7 day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
  FROM attr_list AS al
  JOIN dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
  GROUP BY al.user_id) AS al
ON al.user_id = c.user
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for thank you! I didn't think about just creating that alias in the subquery

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but my intuition is suggesting something like this might be what you are looking for....

```
Round((sum(IF(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ), al.Number_of_dealers, 0))  / al.Number_of_dealers) * 100 ,2)  as Percentage_up_to_date
```

....except that seems to result in 200%. (Probably because it doesn't, and couldn't, "distinct" the previous counts' shared dealers?).

---

UPDATE: From your feedback, I would suggest you can possibly avoid the subquery altogether if you include the JOIN and WHERE from it in the main query, then you could do something like `sum(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ))  / count(*)`.

...though your use of LEFT JOIN makes me question this suggestion.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in my actual query but it may help to clarify. So basically ```al.Number_of_dealers``` is being set by the sub-select and I want to say ```of the dealers from this sub-select /*a.Number_of_dealers*/, get a count of the ones where curdate() < next_call_date + 7 days```

Comment: Thank you, I see where you're going. Can you clarify what you mean  by questioning the use of the left join? That's being used to join the attr_list table which is only necessary in retrieving the dealers associated with the users and that is working, but getting the next_call_date for only those users has been my hang up . Maybe I just need a better structured query in general

Comment: I meant it made me question the effectiveness of what I was suggesting; it complicates things. Initially, it looks like the current left join & subquery part could be replaced with something *like* `left join attr_list AS al ON d.csr = al.data AND al.attr_id = 14`; but with the way `dealers` is joined differently in the subquery and outer query, that is probably wrong as well.